# Activity closing when fetching json data

Tags: android, json

i am creating this android app which fetches some data and then shows notification after particular interval. but whenever i run it, it just closes. here's the code i'm using. it's getting some data from previous activity.

```
package com.example.boschcarservice;



import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;
    private static String url_all_products = "http://bosch-car-mohali.com/home/boschcar/android_connect/get_product_details.php";

    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "products";
    private String TAG_PID = null;
    JSONArray products = null;
    TextView t1,t2,t3;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        t1= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        t2= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
        t3= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView7);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        TAG_PID=extras.getString("pid");
        productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Loading products in Background Thread
        new LoadAllProducts().execute();

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        String dt= t3.getText().toString();
        try {
            calendar.setTime(sdf.parse(dt));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, MyReciever.class);
        PendingIntent pi= PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, myIntent,0);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),10*24*60*60*1000, pi);
    }

    class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading products. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }
        /**
         * getting All products from url
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // products found
                    // Getting Array of Products
                    products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                    // looping through All Products
                    for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable
                        String pid = c.getString(TAG_PID);

                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(TAG_PID, pid);

                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        productsList.add(map);
                    }
                } else {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connection Error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    t1.setText(productsList.get(1).toString());
                    t2.setText(productsList.get(3).toString());
                    String dt = t1.getText().toString();  // Start date
                    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                    try {

                        c.setTime(sdf.parse(dt));

                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    c.add(Calendar.DATE, 15);  // number of days to add, can also use Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH in place of Calendar.DATE
                    SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                    t3.setText(sdf1.format(c.getTime()).toString()); 

                }
            });


        }

    }



    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }


}
```

EDIT:
here are the logs

```
12-06 16:30:57.947: E/AndroidRuntime(827): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-06 16:30:57.947: E/AndroidRuntime(827): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
12-06 16:30:57.947: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
12-06 16:30:57.947: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
12-06 16:30:57.947: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
12-06 16:30:57.947: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
12-06 16:30:57.947: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
12-06 16:30:57.947: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
12-06 16:30:57.947: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
12-06 16:30:57.947: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
12-06 16:30:57.947: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
12-06 16:30:57.947: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
12-06 16:30:57.947: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
12-06 16:30:57.947: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at com.example.boschcarservice.JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(JSONParser.java:61)
12-06 16:30:57.947: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at com.example.boschcarservice.gpass$1.run(gpass.java:78)
12-06 16:30:57.947: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
12-06 16:30:57.947: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-06 16:30:57.947: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-06 16:30:57.947: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
12-06 16:30:57.947: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-06 16:30:57.947: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-06 16:30:57.947: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
12-06 16:30:57.947: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
12-06 16:30:57.947: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Is it crashing. if so please paste the logs

Comment: added copy of logcat file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error means that you are trying to do some network-related stuff inside the main or UI thread.

The problem with trying to do that is that if the network takes a long time to respond, the UI will be frozen and thus it would be a bad user experience.

To avoid this, Android expects you to do anything that is not UI related outside of the UI thread. In this case you should create an AsyncTask like suggested in another answer, and then put all your network-related code there.

Then you can kick off this AsynTask in the UI thread and if the network happens to time out or respond slowly, the UI will keep working.

Basically, an AsyncTask will create a new thread that executes your code via the doInBackground() method. Then [as per the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html):

> onPostExecute(Result), invoked on the UI thread after the background
>   computation finishes. The result of the background computation is
>   passed to this step as a parameter

And thus you can get the info back from the AyncTask and then do something in the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Asynctask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to make the network call.
The [excpetion](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html) is clearly evident. The network call is made on UI thread and its not supposed to be performed

Comment: so i need to do the work i'm doing in background thread in the main ?? sorry i couldn't understand you. this is my first time working with json. can you explain using the name of functions?